# discrepancy in total time vs time as RU/US

Tags: battlefield-3

My stats show that I've got total of 228h 34m spent in BF3. However awards progress stats show, that for US service medal I'm at 88h 20m, and RU service medal at 89h 59m. That's 178h 19m total progress towards both service medals.

Where did the remaining 50 hours go?

Comment: The 50 hours were probably spent waiting for multiplayer games to start, or in the menus. Total time spent is usually counted from the moment you launch the executable, until the moment you exit it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it can be that another 50 hours are just the time that you were dead or playing other game modes, where is no RU and US(for example SQDM or Scavenger or whatever else). I have 212 hours total, 78 for US and 69 for RU

Comment: @Novarg: Scavenger still has US vs RU; SQDM makes sense, although I hardly ever play that mode, so no way that would make up 50h.

Comment: @Nolonar: yeah, that would make sense. If you could find any reference for that, I'll gladly accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service medals are the US Marines service medal and the RU service medal, both awarded for spending 100 hours in either service. As with the class service medals (Engineer, Medic, Recon, Support), only time spent as *a foot soldier* in-game counts. So any time spent in vehicles, aircraft, stationary weapons, does not count.

[image: RU Service Medal] [image: USMC Service Medal]

Note that time dead does not count towards your total play time, just like time in the menus. I can't confirm, but am led to believe this by seeing the BF3stats.com's reports ([example](http://bf3stats.com/stats_360/iamthesgt/reports#rep_80313986)). Note the round Duration (7:13 in the example) and the 'Time' field for the player (6:08 in the example). BF3stats.com pulls its data from the BF3 API, so I assume the reason that field is there is to calculate SPM.

I believe (but can't confirm) that time spent playing Squad Deathmatch counts as play time for the RU Army.

Comment: found this:http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/threadview/2832654624823279981/, which seems to corroborate your answer